# PDF Indirect references and incremental updates

Tags: pdf

Reading the [PDF 1.7 reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf), I'm wondering about this quote on page 99:

> When a consumer application read the file, it must build its cross-reference information in such a way that the most recent copy of each object is the one accessed in the file.

Let's say a dictionary (`3 0 obj`) references an indirect object `4 0 R`. What if you incrementally update this object to make `4 1 obj`? When the PDF-reading application reads the reference `4 0 R` of `3 0 obj`, but only has information about `4 1 obj` in its internal xref table - is it still correct to use the `4 1 obj`? Or do you have to update all the referencing objects when updating an indirect object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“PDF 32000-1:2008 - 7.3.10 Indirect Objects” declares:

> […] Together, the combination of an object number and a generation number shall uniquely identify an indirect object. […]

You **must not** update a generation number if you update an object!
A generation number update can only occur if the object is deleted as described in “PDF 32000-1:2008 - 7.5.4 Cross-Reference Table”:

> […] When an indirect object is deleted, its cross-reference entry shall be marked free […]. The entry’s generation number shall be incremented by 1 to indicate the generation number to be used the next time an object with that object number is created.